# Troubleshooting IP lockout issue(permission denied) with linux Apache server and MODx CMS

Tags: apache-http-server

I've been tasked with trying to resolve a IP lockout issue on a site served with an Apache Linux server and a MODx CMS.

Only users on a particular network are locked out of the CMS url. Everyone else can access.

The first thing I need to resolve is whether this network lockout is being caused by Apache or MODX.

I am NOT an Apache or MODx guru so would appreciate ANY useful tips or feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Did a recursive grep search on the error string 'restricted access' and followed the chain to the php class listing the IPs